# GA Custom Variables within Facebook Instant Artice

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, facebook-instant-articles

We want to find the best way to track FB Instant Articles in GA beyond what the FB developer documentation can help us with. Custom Variables seems like a good approach considering the following scenario.

They are currently live and publish from an RSS Feed and are selected via Echobox. This means the Source/Medium becomes automatically taken over by Echobox so the regular UTM Source/Medium method is out of the picture.

I was thinking about the Pros and Cons of implementing Custom Variables. GTag Manager is not compatible though. Any feedback is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Custom variables are deprecated in Universal Analytics on favor of custom dimensions. What exactly do you mean with "Google Tag Manager is not compatible" ?

Comment: Facebook Instant Articles does not allow setting a Google Tag Manager container.

And yes, using Custom Dimensions not variables.